# Enable GRUB after disabling it in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I wanted to disable the GRUB selection menu and boot directly to windows without any prompt just as if there was no Linux.

I achieved the solution for the above by grub customisation menu and selecting the windows chain msloader as 1st priority and setting the time out to 0.

(I think that was not the correct way to do it, though it works perfect.)

My question is *how do I restore GRUB* ?

I dont see GRUB and the system just proceeds with windows since I had set the timer to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the Ubuntu (DVD/USB) installation media - select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Once you are on the Ubuntu Live desktop - open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt  
sudo nano /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

Make sure that these variables are set :

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then re-installl the GRUB boot loader :

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
```

Note : `sdX` = disk | `sdXX` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use GParted - it is included in the Ubuntu install media.
Now you can select which operating system you want to boot from the GRUB boot menu.